# 'WHERE IN' in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `tuition_info` with data in following structure:

```
id    from    to    location
1     0.00    2.00  2,3,6,9
2     2.00    3.00  1,2,4,5
3     3.00    4.00  3,4,5
```

Now I want a query something like as following:

```
SELECT * FROM tuition_info WHERE 2 IN (location);
```

Means it will return 1st and 2nd row from the above table. Here `location` type is `'text'`.

How can I do this in mysql? Please give some idea.

Comment: Are you looking to match text? if location matches xxx text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`FIND_IN_SET`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM tuition_info WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, location) > 0;
```

#### [<kbd>**SQLFiddle**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efb7ef/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the like operator.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tuition_info
WHERE location LIKE '%2%';
```

Comment: It's unreliable to just bring back something with `2,` or `,2` in it. It'll bring back results with `203` in them.